# how check two forms validation in django form?

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am using the Django authentication system and have another model which is about user:

```
class user(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_code=models.IntegerField(max_length=3)
    phone=models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
    task=models.ForeignKey(task)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user_code', 'task')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.user_code)
```

so I made two forms for user registeration(form.py):

```
class userForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        widgets = {'password': forms.PasswordInput(),}

class Form4(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=user
```

Now in my view I want to send two forms to template and submit both of them. Everything is well but after submitting I can't check form validation? this is my view:

```
def add_new_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        user_form = userForm(request.POST) # django User
        form = Form4(request.POST)      # my model user
        if user_form.is_valid() and form.is_valid():          # All validation rules pass **edited** is_valide
            user_name=user_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = user_form.cleaned_data['password']
            name=user_form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            user_id = form.cleaned_data['user_code']
            email = user_form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            task = form.cleaned_data['task']
        else:  # **added** form invalid statement
            return render(request, 'student/form4.html', {'form': form,'user_form':user_form})

        try:  #**moved from valid statement**
            do somthing...  
        except ValueError :
            do somthing...       
     else:
        form = Form4()
        user_form=userForm()
        # An unbound form
        return render(request, 'student/form4.html', {'form': form,'user_form':user_form})
```

this is my template(form4.html):

```
<form name="myForm" action="{% url 'student:add_new_user' %}" onsubmit="return validateForm4();"     method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div id="form-data">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            {{ user_form.username }}{{ user_form.username.errors }}
            <label for="id_user_name">user name:</label><br>
            {{ user_form.password }}{{ user_form.password.errors }}
            <label for="id_password">password:</label><br>
            {{ user_form.first_name }}{{ user_form.first_name.errors }}
            <label for="id_name">first name:</label><br>
            {{ user_form.email }}{{ user_form.email.errors }}
            <label for="id_email">email:</label><br>

            {{ form.user_code }}{{ form.user_code.errors }}
            <label for="id_email">use ID:</label><br>

            {{ form.phone }}{{ form.phone.errors }}
            <label for="id_phone">phone number:</label><br>

            {{ form.task }}{{ form.task.errors }}
            <label for="id_task">task:</label><br>
            <input type="submit" value="register" /><br>
        </div>
    </form>
```

But it returns False for both validation. How can I check validation?

**ANSWER**:

I add which field I want from User and user. and change my "form.py" to :

```
class userForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
       model=User
       fields = ('username', 'password','first_name','email' )
       widgets = {'password': forms.PasswordInput(),}
class Form4(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=user
        fields = ('user_code', 'phone','task' )
```

thanks for all comments and answer.

Comment: typo mistake maybe- this line: `if user_form.is_valide and form.is_valid()` >> here `user_form.is_valide` should be `user_form.is_valid()`

Comment: Side question: Is it possible to name a Model "user"?

Comment: ruddra: excuse me I make this mistake when I past it here.

Comment: mevius: yes it's possible becouse django have "User".

Comment: Normally if is_valid() returns false you should see an error message in you template, if you render {{form}} and {{user_form}} I think you miss the RequestContext: return render_to_response('student/form4.html', {'form': form,'user_form':user_form}, context_instance = RequestContext(request))

Comment: @rnevius it is a python class, so even you have `auth.models.User` and `my_module.User` in same module you can import it with `from my_module import User as MyUser`. Django only has fields name restrictions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#field-name-restrictions

Comment: @madzohan thanks for the explanation. I was aware of the field name restrictions, but didn't consider you could import `as` another name. Great!

Comment: @het.oosten he used `render` in `else` statement https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render it uses a RequestContext by default.

Comment: I've made some edits in your question

Comment: try add to your template `{{ form.non_field_errors }} {{ user_form.non_field_errors }}` now if one of your forms invalid -you can see it in your template

Comment: and read this docs, whole page https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages

Comment: @madzohan thanks alot.But still I get false.Is it true I writing user_form = userForm(request.POST) # django User
form = Form4(request.POST)      # my model user ?

Comment: I add my template to question.

Comment: you haven't added `{{ user_form.non_field_errors }}` (reason is if you didn't render some fields manually) anyway add this and submit, it should reload this page with errors

Answer (score 0):

Try add different prefixes to each of forms

```
# GET
user_form = userForm(prefix="one")
form = Form4(prefix="two")

# POST
user_form = userForm(request.POST, prefix="one")
form = Form4(request.POST, prefix="two")
```